# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 107 but got 105 bytes)

Tags: java, tomcat7

i publish a program on tomcat,but these errors occur, i really don't know why.
i just guess is the ftp tools problem.

this is the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Jar: aopalliance-1.0.jar
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 107 but got 105 bytes)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:403)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:195)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getBytes(JarInputStream.java:112)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.checkManifest(JarInputStream.java:94)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:86)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.getManifest(ExtensionValidator.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:194)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: can you please post the code causing this error?

Comment: Try opening that jar with a ZIP tool (like 7Zip) and see if that works. If not, your file is damaged. If it does, you have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: The 'error image' was redundant, as you had already posted the text, and posting images of text is just a complete waste of our bandwidth anyway, not to mention your time. Your question is incomplete without the code that throws this exception *and* the code that produced the data.

Answer (score 0):

You mention FTP.

Might you be transferring/FTP'ing a BINARY file (the zip arcvhive) in ASCII mode from your FTP Client?